# How to check notification permissions on the main thread in swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, xcode9

I've got a function in my code to check if we can have permission to display a UILocalNotification.

```
open func hasPermission() -> Bool {
    if let permissions = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings {
        if permissions.types.contains(.alert) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This code has triggered a warning in Xcode 9:

> UI API called from background thread:
>   UIApplication.currentUserNotificationSettings must be used from main
>   thread only

How do I fix this? I know there is the `DispatchQueue.main.async` method, just not sure how to implemented that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if hasPermission() {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: This is part of a background job, so I'd prefer to do as little as possible on the main thread. This particular check is done as a guard hasPermission() else {